# Node.js res.setheader is not a function at _respond

Tags: node.js

I am getting the following error when making helper functions for node.js.  When I had it not in a helpersFunction.js it was working just fine.  How should one properly setup helper functions in Node.js?

> TypeError: res.setheader is not a function
>       at _respond (/Users/camdixon/Sites/node/node_api2/helperFunctions.js:8:7)
>       at Object.module.exports.success (/Users/camdixon/Sites/node/node_api2/helperFunctions.js:15:3)
>       at /Users/camdixon/Sites/node/node_api2/routes.js:14:13
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/camdixon/Sites/node/node_api2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/Users/camdixon/Sites/node/node_api2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)

helperFunctions.js file

```
function _respond(res, next, status, data, http_code) {
  var response = {
    'status': status,
    'data': data
  };

  res.setheader('content-type', 'application/json');
  res.writeHead(http_code);
  res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
  return next();
}

module.exports.success = function(res, next, data) {
  _respond(res, next, 'OK', data, 200);
}

module.exports.failure = function(res, next, data, http_code) {
  _respond(res, next, 'Error', data, http_code);
}
```

My Routes.js file

```
var helpers = require('./helperFunctions.js');

module.exports = function (app) {

  var list = {}

  app.post('/list/create', function(req, res, next) {
    list = req.body.email_address;
    console.log(list);

    helpers.success(res, next, list);
  });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the stacktrace you will notice that you have a typo; the method is called setHeader not setheader.

Comment: Where do I find the defined functions for these responses?

Comment: You can find it in the official nodejs documentation: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse